# Updating third table where id didnot match from other 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables

Table A

```
ID  Remark  
1   NULL    
2   Null    
4   Null
```

Table B

```
ID  Remark  
1   Null    
2   Null    
4   Null
```

Table C

```
ID      
1   
2   
3
```

I want to update Table B Remark by joining Table A and Table C where records in Table A does not exist in Table C.

So final Output will look like

Table B

```
ID  Remark  
1   Null    
2   Null    
4   Invalid Entry
```

I have tried so far below query:

```
Update TableB set Remark='Invalid'
where not exists ( select ID from TableA join TableC on  TableA.ID=TableC.ID)
```

But I think there is some problem. Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to connect TableB to the exists

```
Update TabB
set Remark='Invalid'
from TableB TabB
where not exists 
(
select 1 
from TableA 
join TableC 
on  TableA.ID=TableC.ID 
where TabB.id = TableA.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `not in`:

```
Update TableB
    set Remark = 'Invalid'
    where id not in (select a.ID from TableA a join TableC c on a.ID = c.ID);
```

Or, alternatively, you want to update when the `id` is not in both `TableA` and `TableC`.  I find this easier to follow:

```
Update b
    set Remark = 'Invalid'
    from TableB b
    where not exists (select 1 from TableA a where a.id = b.id) and
          not exists (select 1 from TableC c where c.id = b.id) ;
```